# How to use zenburn with a darker background?

Tags: colors

I have Emacs 24.5.1, installed `zenburn-theme` off of melpa-stable and loaded the theme in my `.emacs` with `(load-theme 'zenburn)`. I like all the colours except the background. It's a bit too bright.

How do I set the background colour to a darker colour?

Answer (score 9):

You can modify zenburn's face definitions in your .emacs.  I use this to avoid mucking up the background of other themes.

```
(with-eval-after-load "zenburn-theme"
  (zenburn-with-color-variables
    (custom-theme-set-faces
     'zenburn
     ;; original `(default ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-fg :background ,zenburn-bg))))
     `(default ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-fg :background ,zenburn-bg-1)))))))
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks!  For those who are interested, you can use `zenburn-bg-05`, `zenburn-bg-1`, or `zenburn-bg-2` for varying shades of darkness.

Comment: That works for me on startup, but when I reload `.emacs` with `M-x load-file` I get the brighter background again? Why could that be happening? (Using emacs --daemon)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of the background by adding this to your .emacs file:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:background "blue"))))
 )
```

Note, the core bit here is:

```
'(default ((t (:background "blue"))))
```

As you might already have `custom-set-faces` declared if you made any modifications previously.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at the `hc-zenburn` theme (`hc-zenburntheme` on MELPA).  It probably changes more than just the background, but the darker background is all that I generally notice.